# How to install python and all its modules when passing code to somebody in Windows

Tags: python, batch-file

Is there a way of batching things up in Windows to install `python 3.5` as well as all the necessary modules which come with my code (e.g. `matplotlib`, `numpy`, `pyodbc` etc)?

I want to pass my code to **non-technical person**, who can't be bothered to be asked to run things in cmd, otherwise they might give up thinking that it's not a straighforward procedure.

All I want to pass is one batch file to run (which enables to install all the necessary stuff including python 3.5 itself) and my code. Is there any easy way to do that? Thanks!